# Remove zeros from first of numbers in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

In Android EditText, inputType is number. I don't want to have zero(s) before other numbers. I mean when user enters 0 and after that enters 3, it will show 03 but I want to have 3. I know I can use textwatcher. But is there better solution?!

Comment: cant you use addTextChangedListener?

Comment: May I use any special inputType to do this? @AjayKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative way in which you can use textWatcher .Check length of editable text inside afterTextChange method. If length is 1 and string is 0 than remove 0 .

**EDIT:**

```
editTextPack.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        if (s.toString().trim().length() == 1 && s.toString().trim().equals("0")) {

                        editTextPack.setText("");                             
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                  int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
```

Something like that.

Comment: What about 003 or 0003?!

Comment: Using afterTextChange he will not able to write more then one Zero

Comment: See my Edit, you can do it inside onTextChanged or afterTextChanged